# Can i reference the index of a "for each" loop without a counter?

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I am wondering if there is an index attribute for the object of a for each loop.

The simple answer is to include a counter variable within the for each loop, independent from the loop itself (as i have done with the i variable in the code) and create the index as you go, but i'm wondering if there is a way of getting the index directly from the loop construct?

```
i = 1
For Each cell In rRange
    MsgBox cell.Index???
    MsgBox i

    i = i + 1
Next cell
```

Obviously, in the case of the code i have provided index is not an attribute I can use. Is there an attribute there which would work like this?

Comment: `.Row` and `.Column`?

Comment: The index you'd need to calculate, as youre using for each, it will be dependant on the collection your iterating.  In the question, you need to use the differences between myrange.cells(1,1).row and cell.row and myrange.cells(1,1).column and cell.column accordingly, not very readable :o)

Comment: Also, you need to think about the index, in the question you're using a range, this will be looped horizontal then vertical, so in a 3x3 range, the 3rd index will be the last cell on the 1st row, not the last cell of the 1st column

Comment: the row or column doesn't matter. i just want to know if there's an index telling me the number of loops i've done in the for each as i'm going. i don't know how for each works "under the hood", so to speak. What it's looping on in this case may be a range of cells, but that's just the example i'm using to illustrate the question. It may not always be ranges that I am "for-each"ing through

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general answer is, no, VBA does not provide a way to ascertain the "index" of the loop it's in while executing `For Each`. You might be able to calculate it, as is suggested in a comment, depending on what the object is. But there's nothing inherent in VBA that can do this for you. A counter is, indeed, the only way that "always" works.

Comment: Be careful! There is no guarantee the for each will iterate sequentially over the collection or range. For example, the indexes of the elements of the for each could be 1, 7, 3, 8, 2,...

Comment: This is true - which is why I specifired "index of the loop it's in while executing". May I include your more exact comment in the answer, @PaulOgilvie?

Comment: @PaulOgilvie can you please elaborate on that? There must be some kind of lower level object that knows where the loop has been and where it's going.

Comment: The lower level data structure may be a linked list where items got added in the order they are created, or is an array where items get added in the first available free slot yet get an index that is last+1, or is some other data structure. Walking this data structure in the for-each retrieves the items in this internal order (next list element, next array element). But since we don't know the implementation of this lower level object, we don't know in which order the items are retrieved.